# Associations many_many NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

hello everyone i just had this problem i was following tutorial, i was trying to create many to many association between my article and category so i added article_category model by typing:

```
rails g model article_category article_id:integer category_id:integer
```

and inside the this model i typed

```
belongs_to :article
belongs_to :category
```

inside article.rb:

```
has_many :article_categories
has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
```

and inside category.rb:

```
has_many :article_categories
has_many :articles, through: :article_categories
```

so i went to the console:to associate by typing the following:

```
Article.all
Article.first
```

ad i checked article.categories

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

and i tried on category as well

```
category.all
category.first
```

and the results was:

```
category
 => #<Category id: 6, name: "sport", created_at: "2016-04-11 06:41:25", updated_at: "2016-04-11 06:41:25">
article
 => #<Article id: 25, title: "kkkk", description: "lll", created_at: "2016-04-13 07:32:38", updated_at: "2016-04-13 07:32:38", user_id: 21>
```

so i tried to make this article part of this category by typing:

```
category.articles << article
```

so i got this error:

```
INSERT INTO `article_categories` (`article_id`, `category_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (25, 6, '2016-04-18 09:06:58', '2016-04-18 09:06:58')
   (12.9ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFiJj.png)
any idea guys 
thanks

[image: category controller]

[image: application controller]

[image: category controller]

Comment: Can you please past the result of this: `category.errors.full_messages`?

Comment: it just give me empty hash []

Comment: This is weird! have you tried to check : `article.categories << category` ? Try and post the result...

Comment: @AdelAlmaleh Do you have any callbacks like `before_save` etc.?

Comment: @usmanali no but i just upload my controller you can check it out

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli it gives me same error

Answer (score 0):

Try adding indexes on your join model's (article_category) migration.

```
add_index :article_categories, :article_id
add_index :article_categories, :category_id
```

That should solve the problem if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

can you try `category.article_ids << article_ids`?

for many-many I think rails enables you to use the _ids which will save the id instead of the whole object you want.

then you can access `category.articles` and check if the article was indeed added

Comment: undefined local variable or method `article_ids' for main:Object

Comment: can you comment here a sample output of `category.articles` ? thanks.  
you can check this link  
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html   
and see the part for "has_many", the Example part.  
it says that it adds _ids helper.

Comment: If all else fails, try restarting your rails server